# Creating vertical polygons in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon-creation

I am trying to convert vertical line (cross-section) features to the polygon, but all regular ArcGIS tools (e.g. Feature to Polygon) that I applied can't convert vertical lines to vertical polygons.

Do you know a tool that can do it automatically?

[image: line feature that I need to convert to polygon]

I also have point feature class with *xyz* coordinates of every point[image: points with xyz values]

Comment: I suppose you want to compute discharge with sub-section method. I would use each vertical as input taking account `i + i+1` pair of points to create `n` polygons. If verticals are equal-spaced, create a set of vertical lines to split the dissolved polygon of image 1

Comment: You should be able to do it using cursors (search/update/insertcursor, http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) and the shape tokens. That way you could read the Z values and write these as X or Y values. Will be a bit tricky though..

Comment: @Fran: Are the points in the correct order or is the order ~random?

Comment: if the lines are equal in distance, you can create buffer on the vertical lines.

Comment: @BERA points are in correct order, spacing between points is 1 cm and every point has its own unique ID

Answer (score 0):

I have not done any testing, but from the documentation it sounds like ArcGIS 3D Analyst supports [Creating a vertical line segment](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/creating-a-vertical-line-segment.htm).

However, [3D polygon interiors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/editing-polygons-in-3d.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_3B4C5581378E4B5F99EBAD82E7F561F2) present additional challenges so:

> Completely vertical polygons are not supported in the geodatabase as
>   they are flagged as zero-area polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the point feature, try Geoprocessing/"Coordinate Table To Polygon" to create the polygon, if it throws an error of invalid parameters, export you xyz collection to a .csv, then use this csv as input. After that you should have a polygon, then you can use the Edit/Divide tool to get vertical polygons, you can specify the width(*Equal Width* radio button) and the direction to divide the polygon. Note that even specifying the width, the number of parts must be set, but that you can calculate from the polyline collection.
[image: example]